# Calling pre/post script after Eclipse p2 upgrade?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

Let's say, I have an application (a bunch of features) installed in Eclipse. Now, I have a new version of the p2 repository for that application and ready for the same Eclipse to be upgraded for the new version of that application.

Is there any way, I can hook a post process script after p2 upgrade?

I know p2 touchpoint can hook some actions for installation, but that is only pre/post actions for each plugin or feature.

What I want is one single action before and after the whole upgrade (not individual plugin/feature installation).

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your plugins and features in a single feature, and attach a p2 touchpoint to that wrapping feature.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But that doesn't work in our case. Our application is composed by modules. Some of the modules have dependencies. Also, people can chose what modules to install. Simply including everything in one feature won't work.

Comment: I doubt that this is correct. AFAIK, p2 doesn't guarantee an order in which the touchpoints are executed. Or in other words: touchpoints are assumed to only operate on the artifact they are associated with. If they do process other artifacts as well, this can only work by chance.